# PHP memory issue; Mac uses more than Windows

Tags: php, arrays, macos, memory, ram

I’m trying to figure out why my test script takes up more memory on my Macbook Air than on my Windows laptop.

Here is the php script:

```
<?php
$mem = (memory_get_usage() / 1024) / 1024;
echo ("memory in current use: $mem MB");

$test = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 50000; $i++)
{
    $test[$i] = ($i % 1024) * 2;
}

$mem = (memory_get_usage() / 1024) / 1024;
echo ("memory in current use: $mem MB");
?>
```

results on MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2014:
memory in current use: 0.20581817627 MB
memory in current use: 7.19153594971 MB

results on Acer Aspire V3-771 laptop:
memory in current use: 0.11331939697266 MB
memory in current use: 4.178352355957 MB

As you can see, the mac takes up 3 MB more.

---

and finally the specs of the machines:
MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2014) specs:
CPU: 1,4 GHz Intel Core i5
MEM: 4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
SYS: OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)
PHP: Apache 2.2.29 (MAMP) PHP/5.6.2

Acer Aspire V3-771 laptop specs:
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50Ghz 2.50 GHz
MEM: 4 GB (3,84 GB usable)
SYS: Windows 7
PHP: apache/2.4.10 (win32) PHP/5.6.3

Comment: that's kind of a flippant non-answer, seeing how php is interpreted and the script and data live in binary structs that pack the same on both.  It would have been funnier if it had been true.

Comment: and yet it clearly is true

Answer (score 0):

I suspect windows is running a 32-bit version of php, and the mac 64-bit.  I've seen the memory usage difference myself.

Was: would this happen to be 64-bit mac and 32-bit windows?  I've seen that myself

Comment: Both seem to be 64 bit.

Comment: I wonder what the win32 in the PHP: apache/2.4.10 (win32) represents.  Can 64-bit windows run 32-bit apps?  Is win php 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: yeah, they can. Maybe that's the problem? I never knew the 64bit vs 32bit could be an issue. I thought that was only about making the CPU read the RAM more efficiently :(

If this is really the problem; is it possible to run 32bit apps on macos?

Comment: it's the tradeoff, yes.  on these 64-bit systems integers and pointers are 8 bytes each; on a 32-bit system only 4 bytes.  It would be possible to build a 64-bit system that had 8-byte integers and 4-byte pointers, which would help php a lot I think, but nobody seems interested.  So running a 64-bit OS effectively halves your laptop's memory.

Comment: was neither critique nor clarification, it was how I answered the question.  But to make it more obvious, I rephrased it.